# Why would Rust allow multiple mutable references here?

Tags: rust

I am an experienced C++ programmer and just getting started with Rust. I was reading some documents on Rust online and was under an impression that below code snippet should not be allowed.

```
fn main() { 
    let mut s = String::from("hello world");  // creates String
    let wr:& mut String = &mut s; // wr is a mutable (writable reference)
        
    // let rr:& String = &s; // not allowed: cannot borrow 's' as immutable as it's already borrowed as mutable by wr.

    wr.clear(); // ALLOWED. Borrowed as a mutable reference.
    s.clear(); // ALLOWED. Borrowed as a mutable reference

    let ss:& str = &s[..5]; // ALLOWED. Borrowed as a immutable reference. It's a race condition.
}
```

Rust compiler will not let me create rr because reference is already been taken as immutable by 'wr'. I completely understand that. But my question is don't I still have 2 mutable references to memory pointed to by s? I could change the state of s as I demonstrated by using clear() on wr and s. And at the last line, I am borrowing a immutable reference to s while trying to slice the string. Why Rust is not considering 's' in borrowing rules?

Comment: The mutable borrow in `wr` no longer exists after the last place it is used (`wr.clear()`), so the immutable borrow after it is fine. What makes you think that is a race condition?

Comment: @Herohtar Thanks, I think I have the answer. I thought wr shouldn't be allowed since s was borrowed as mutable at the declaration time but I think s isn't borrowed out as a mutable reference until s.clear(). Declaring s as mutable means that it could be borrowed as a mutable reference but doesn't mean that it's borrowed right there at the declaration time.

Comment: Right, `s` is just a mutable variable and nothing is borrowed at that point. `wr` is the first mutable borrow.

Comment: @Harveer correct, also note that Rust 2015 did behave the way you thought, as its borrows were *lexical* so a borrow would last until the end of a block. Since 2018 borrows are non-lexical and the borrow scope ends as soon as possible. Here the `wr` borrow of `s` goes from line 3 to line 7, then there is an implicit borrow line 8, and finally the `ss` borrow from line 10.